# How can you find a literal percent sign (%) in PostgreSQL using a LIKE query?

Tags: postgresql, sql-like

I have `character varying` entries in a table where *some* (not all) values contain percentages, e.g., `'12%'`, `'97%'`, etc. I want to find all the values that contain percentages. In other words, I want to find all values that end with a percent sign (`'%'`).

Comment: Don't forget that underscores and backslashes also need escaping.

Answer (score 37):

You can try like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table  WHERE my_column LIKE '%\%%' ESCAPE '\';
```

**Format**

```
 <like predicate> ::=
      <match value> [ NOT ] LIKE <pattern>
        [ ESCAPE <escape character> ]

 <match value> ::= <character value expression>

 <pattern> ::= <character value expression>

 <escape character> ::= <character value expression>
```

Comment: If you have `standard_conforming_strings` option turned off (can be checked by `show standard_conforming_strings;`), you need to double backslashes:
`SELECT * FROM my_table  WHERE my_column LIKE '%\\%%' ESCAPE '\\';`
And in both cases (regardless of `standard_conforming_strings`) you can use escape string syntax with doubled backslashes:
`SELECT * FROM my_table  WHERE my_column LIKE E'%\\%%' ESCAPE E'\\';`

Comment: But what will happens when I use a PreparedStatement? Thank you.

Comment: What's the purpose of `ESCAPE '\'` clause? The query works fine without that.

Comment: There is no need to use "\" specifically. You can use any ASCII char as long as you put it into the ESCAPE clause;

Answer (score 21):

You have to escape the literal % sign. By default the escape character is the backslash:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table  WHERE my_column LIKE '%\%';
```

In this case the first `%` sign matches any starting sequence in `my_column`. The remaining `\%` are interpreted as a literal % character. The combination is therefore: match anything that ends in a % character.

[**SQLFiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7beb6/1)

Answer (score 4):

I ended up using regular expressions:

```
select * from my_table where my_column ~ '%$';
```

However, I'd still like to know if it's possible using the `LIKE` operator/comparison.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE  "*To match a literal underscore or percent sign without matching other characters, the respective character in pattern must be preceded by the escape character*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name is giving documentation for the [PostgreSQL `LIKE` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE), but @magnus is giving a workaround which uses the regex matching, aka [~ operator; Match (regex) case-sensitive](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/6.3/c09.htm) aka [regexp_like](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-VS-XQUERY)... does the percent sign have special meaning in a regex pattern? I think not; so no need to escape it, right? That's why @magnus does it; to avoid escaping %; it's clever.