# Searching for partial strings in Ecto using ilike

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am trying to search in a database to see if a string matches part of another string in the database. I can get it to match if the two are exact using `ilike`, but when I am searching for just part of the string it does not catch data that contains it. Here is what my code looks like for the query:

```
    servicesstate = Repo.all(from p in Callme.Service, where: ilike(p.locations, ^zip.state))
```

It will match when the values are exact ("South Carolina", "South Carolina"), but I want it to match when it is something like ("Located in South Carolina", "South Carolina")

Thanks

Answer (score 21):

You can use the `%` syntax for LIKE/ILIKE:

```
servicesstate = Repo.all(from p in Callme.Service, where: ilike(p.locations, ^"%#{zip.state}%"))
```

Note that this will not work correctly if `zip.state` contains a `%`. If it can contain `%`, you'll have to use [`Ecto.Query.API.fragment/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#fragment/1) with a query like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007164/how-can-you-find-a-literal-percent-sign-in-postgresql-using-a-like-query).

Comment: The best idea to express apprecation is to vote up and also check this answer as a solution of your problem.

Comment: Does `ilike(p.locations, ^"%#{user_input}%")` allow SQL injection?

Comment: @NathanLong nope. Just answered your latest question related to this moments ago :)

Comment: @Dogbert and for the benefit of those here, what was your answer?

Comment: Never mind, here is @Dogbert's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41021806/281199

Comment: @cayblood thanks for the link! The short answer for future readers is, no, it doesn't allow SQL injection.

Comment: Note that, although injection of SQL *statements* is impossible, LIKE injections are still possible (as documented in Ecto: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#like/2) that can significantly slow down queries. This requires some sort of user input sanitising.