# Pass % wild card character as string from C# to search postgres table record that contains %

Tags: c#, postgresql, wildcard

Search a  table record that **contains and or starts with** wildcard character %
using the below query works. But how to pass % from C# as string and query the postgres table that **contains and or starts with** %.

**Starts with Query**
select * from somepostgrestable
where table_column like
'%%'
--ESCAPE ''
limit 5;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you find a literal percent sign (%) in PostgreSQL using a LIKE query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007164/how-can-you-find-a-literal-percent-sign-in-postgresql-using-a-like-query)

Comment: Why is your `ESCAPE` clause commented out?

Comment: @madreflection In postgres the query is fine but how do you pass it from C# ???? And I commnet out ESCAPE to make sure if it works and it does

Comment: Microsoft's [documentation for strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#declaring-and-initializing-strings) shows you how to do that.

Comment: Should that not be `select * from somepostgrestable where table_column like '%\%%' limit 5` per [Like](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE): *To match a literal underscore or percent sign without matching other characters, the respective character in pattern must be preceded by the escape character. The default escape character is the backslash but a different one can be selected by using the ESCAPE clause. To match the escape character itself, write two escape characters.*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532691/how-do-i-write-a-backslash-in-a-string#:~:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20include,of%20the%20verbatim%20string%20literal.

Comment: Avoid having to Escape altogether with a regular expression where `%` is not a wildcard. `select * from table where col ~ '^%'`. Then you should able to just pass % as any other character.